C# WinForms ImageList throws an error when setting Images in designer
The project is .NET Framework 4.7.2, a Class Library.
So I encountered this error with ImageList where it throws this error whenever I try to add an Image to ImageList.Images collection through the designer's "Images Collection Editor":

The documentation only shows adding Images programatically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imagelist?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
There was also a thread on Telerik's website, someone said the images cannot be added directly from designer, is that true?
Code I'm having problems with:
public ImageList imageList1 { get; set; } = new ImageList();

I'm looking for a solution where you could add Images to some kind of Image list from the designer.
I have already tried ImageCollection, List and List.
They all throw errors when trying to set them in designer.
I expected ImageList to work because of how good it sounded. You could have a list of Images. Thought it could be edited from designer with ease, but official docs don't have any examples of doing it through designer, just programmatically.

Should work out of the box. Just hit "Add", select a file and your set. If you get errors there is presumably something broken in your setup. This hasn't anything to do with Telerik controls right its just a distraction in the question?

Can we assume that this is for a .NET 8 project? Does the same thing happen in another .NET 8 project and/or a .NET Framework 4.8.1 project?

You can add images to the imageList in the designer by following this tutorial.
But if you want to add them to the designer.cs file, you can add this:
// ADD TWO IMAGES MANUALLY
ImageList1.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.error);
ImageList1.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.info);

ImageList1.Images.SetKeyName(4, "error.png");
ImageList1.Images.SetKeyName(5, "info.png");

You need to add the image, then set the key name. Note that I added two images error.png and info.png to the resources.resx.
Just make sure the keys are in order (in this example 4 and 5 are the keys). I chose these numbers because I already have keys [0, 1, 2, 3] as seen in the image below:

Also, in regard to the error you are getting, try the following:

Delete the ImageList1
Make sure you don't have any extra code in the Form.Designer.cs file
you added yourself
Re-add the ImageList1

